# Calibre suddenly crashed

Tags: calibre

I had been using Calibre (downloaded from Ubuntu software center) on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After adding some books to my library and a proper shutdown, the Calibre did not start. From Terminal too it did not get started hence I had to use ^C and it showed the following message. Is there any way to rectify this.

```
neo@neo-OEM:~$ calibre
^CUnable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.
neo@neo-OEM:~$ ^C
```

I tried removing and reinstalling but to no avail. However, the official website shows some incoherent (for me) way to download and install the latest version 0.2.3. If any one could help.

Comment: I use Calibre a lot, but never use MPT at all, nor have I found a reason to use it, so I don't know much about it.  But I did find some discussion on this problem [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/bugs/968/). Perhaps there will be some help.  If you need other help with Calibre, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating MTP.

In a shell, run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[(src)](https://askubuntu.com/a/345807/208574)