# Access mtpfs on the fly from any application

Tags: samsung, mtp

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 witch I want to use to store some sensitive data. I am using the application EDS Lite to store encrypted files in a container, that can be mounted by the TrueCrypt application.

The phone is recognized by Ubuntu but I can't use TrueCrypt to access the files directly on the device.

I understand that that is caused by the mtpfs which is a pull and push file system.

Is there any way I can use TrueCrypt directly with the device without copying the container to my drive encrypting a file and the replacing the old file ?

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to change `witch` to `which` and remove the `Thank you!`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to do this with a new enough version of gvfs *and* if you install CyanogenMod on your phone.

See this answer for guidance on how to upgrade gvfs and why you need CyanogenMod: [Some Ubuntu 13.04 applications cannot access files on MTP-mounted systems. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284762/some-ubuntu-13-04-applications-cannot-access-files-on-mtp-mounted-systems-why)