# Problems detecting android tablet IView 788TPC with mtp-tools

Tags: 14.04, android, mtp

I installed mtp-tools on 14.04 "Trusty" through Software Center. No problems with install. Issuing `mtp-detect'
 results in

'Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: 1.1.6

Listing raw device(s)
   No raw devices found.'

I did some research and found that mtpfs might be required. so installed that with

`:~$ sudo apt-get install mtpfs`

I still get the following result

:~$ mtp-detect
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: 1.1.6

Listing raw device(s)
   No raw devices found.

My research indicates that the mtp-tools package is still under development.

source: http://libmtp.sourceforge.net/

and the documentation is not comprehensive.

source `man mtp-tools` as well as `mtp-detect -h`

I tried adding the PPA from [Are there any plans to improve mtp support on future Ubuntu releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247943/are-there-any-plans-to-improve-mtp-support-on-future-ubuntu-releases) but it seems this is already worked into trusty 14.04 and won't resolve the problem.

Can anyone provide a recommended course of action to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Iview 788TPC doesn't support MTP only USB storage.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with HTC phone running Android 4.2.2.  I would not mount under Ubuntu 14.04.  I fixed it by turning on USB debugging on the phone under Developer Options.  If you can't see developer options there is a way to turn it on - follow directions here http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42

Comment: I tried this but no change in the results. (Other than the response "No need. You are already a developer.")