# How do I access files on an MTP device?

Tags: usb-drive, mtp

I can't play music or view photos from my phone on Ubuntu 14.04. I can browse the files with the Nautilus, but they won't open. Rhythmbox crashes when trying to play music and the photo viewer says "failed to open input stream for file." I have no idea what this means. How can I fix?

*Edit: I just tried copying the file from my phone to my disk, and sure enough it works just fine and now the file opens. After googling some more, someone said you can't stream the file from Android and it has to be copied locally because it's a "functional limitation of MTP." Is this true? It's able to stream in Windows...

Comment: +1. I've been having this problem ever since I got my Samsung Galaxy S3 a couple of years ago, and I only *just* realized that I can copy or delete the files. Why the FUSE file system can't copy the file into memory before file access, I have no idea.

Comment: +1 I finally can import my images and .mp4 files!

Answer (score 0):

it might be a limitation of the MTP implementation in Ubuntu 14.04.  i was having the same problem in 14.04, and i changed the setting on my Android device to PTP instead.  now i can open files directly from the device.  it appears that all of the same files/directories are available in PTP mode, so hopefully this solves your issue.